# Сохранение изображения в png без потери качества

Tags: java, изображения, png

Мне нужно взять изображение для фона, взять другое изображение, сделать CircleCrop по центру и наложить на фоновое. Проблема только в том, что имеет место быть жуткая пикселизация вне зависимости от разрешения накладываемого изображения. 
Например, я беру изображение разрешением 2000х2000, мне нужно ужать его до 150х150, обрезать кругом по центру и наложить по определенным координатам. И получаются дикие пиксели. 
Ниже пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Делал я это так:

```
BufferedImage bg = ImageIO.read(new File("/some/folder/background.png"));

BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/some/folder/image.png"));
img = CircleCrop(img);        

BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) result.getGraphics();

g.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HBGR);

g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(img, 569, 9, 84, 84, null);

ImageIO.write(result, "PNG", new File("/some/folder/result.png"));
```

Естественно, я начал гуглить, попробовал что-то такое:

```
...
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(1.0F);
writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(new File("/some/folder/result.png")));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(result, null, null), param);
```

Получается тупо черная картинка, размером с bg. 
Что я делаю не так? Был бы рад увидеть полный нормальный вариант этого кода, ибо просмотрел кучу примеров и ни один из них не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать следующий метод, то изображения будут масштабироваться без потери качества, и сохранение в png тоже будет происходить нормально:

```
private BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    int type =
            (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE)
                    ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    BufferedImage ret = img;
    int w, h;
    // Use multi-step technique: start with original size, then
    // scale down in multiple passes with drawImage()
    // until the target size is reached
    w = img.getWidth();
    h = img.getHeight();

    do {
        if (w > targetWidth) {
            w /= 2;
            if (w < targetWidth) {
                w = targetWidth;
            }
        }

        if (h > targetHeight) {
            h /= 2;
            if (h < targetHeight) {
                h = targetHeight;
            }
        }

        BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
        Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g2.dispose();

        ret = tmp;
    } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно работать с изображением в субпиксельной точности. То есть сперва увеличить изображение со сглаживанием, выполнить операции над ним, а затем уменьшить.

Попробуйте использовать ImageMagick.

Comment: Даже если не трогать изображение, а просто его уменьшить, проблема та же

Comment: Сложно ожидать многого от встроенных в Java средств. Они ведь были написаны ещё в 1980-х.

Comment: Можете пример кода с ImageMagick привести, применимо к моему примеру?

Comment: Вот неплохой туториал http://www.roseindia.net/jmagick/index.shtml

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь способы попроще? Чтобы не проводить кучу установок и у себя, и на сервере. Тем более, там туториал под винду, а у меня мак и линукс.

Comment: Попроще - написать всё самому.

Comment: Ну, это возможно, но вряд ли проще

Comment: Другие программисты только тем и заняты, что всё пишут за других программистов. Только денег хотят за это.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что отсутствует способ масштабировать изображение без потери качества, просто вы его наверняка не знаете. И не думаю что в java за последние почти 30 лет не усовершенствовали методы по работе с графикой.

Comment: Все уже лет 20 используют ImageMagick, и я в их числе.